# Upload HTML Canvas on register page as image file

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, jquery, register, registration

I have a jQuery signature plugin running on the register page that users must sign before they register which works until HTML Canvas.

What code can I run to upload this canvas image to the server via AJAX so I can then attach this image file to a hidden input for registration?

Comment: I dont think you can upload image via ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Magento UI Uploader component:

Add the below Code in your template file:

```
<div class="upload-wrapper-cover" data-bind="scope: 'uploader1'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   ".upload-wrapper-cover": {
           "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                   "components": {
                           "uploader": {
                                   "maxFileSize": "1500000",
                                   "component": "Magento_Customer/js/form/element/custom-file-uploader",
                                   "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
                                   "allowedExtensions": ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"],
                                   "isLoading": "true",
                                   "uploaderConfig": {
                                        "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/cover'); ?>"
                                   }
                                }

                   }
           }
   }
}
</script>
```

For Uploading the Image using Ajax you need to craete controller Action as below:

```
namespace Ecommerce\Customer\Controller\Account;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Cover extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Embitel\Customer\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save customer cover image action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            try {
                $destinationFolder = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('profile/image');
                $_FILES['files'] = $this->extractInnerArray($_FILES['files']);
                $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(array('fileId' => 'files'));
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
                $response = ['status'=> true,'data'=> $result['file']];
                $response['type'] = 'cover';

            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                    $response = ['status'=> true,'data'=> $e->getMessage()];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $response = ['status'=> true,'data'=> $e->getMessage()];
            }
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $result->setData($response);
            return $result; 
        }

        $this->_redirect('customer/account/edit');
        return;
    }
}
```

To get the image path in response and save into hidden input type. you need to extends the standard `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader`.

Create a new file in your module like below:
    app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/form/element/custom-file-uploader.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader'
], function (Element) {
    'use strict';
    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            fileInputName: ''
        },

        /**
         * Handler of the file upload complete event.
         *
         * @param {Event} e
         * @param {Object} data
         */
        onFileUploaded: function (e, data) {
            var response = data.result; // Here the response data are stored 

            document.getElementById('upload-wrapper-profile').src=response.data; // Hidden Input type Id  
        },
    });
});
```

Hope this help!